# Incorrect elements appended in xml file

Tags: php, xml

I have an xml file running in my server. While everything is working fine in my localserver, but when I upload it on my server, and when many people are using it, I get an error in my xml file.

I am using simplexml in php to read and update data.

For example,
I have the following structure of my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<db>
<uid></uid>
<score></score>
</db>
```

While it works perfectly for some time, but after some time, some elements get appended in my xml file. For example,

```
<db>
<uid></uid>
<score></score>
</db>/score</db>
```

or

```
<db>
<uid></uid>
<score><//score>
</db>
```

or

```
<db>
<uid></uid>
<core></score>
</db>
```

and then I get parsing error. Is it because many people are writing to my xml file at the same time? I am using LOCK_EX so that shouldn't be a problem

This is how I am opening it-

```
$data= new SimpleXMLElement($file, null, true);
```

And this is how I am closing it-

```
file_put_contents($file, $data->asXML(), LOCK_EX);
```

And it works perfectly all right in my localserver. And it works fine for some time when I upload it online but then suddenly weird things happen to my xml file. What's wrong?

**Edit:**

My update code-

```
<?php
include('functions.php');
$winid= $_GET['wid'];
$loseid=$_GET['lid']; 
$winid=intval($winid);
$loseid=intval($loseid);
$file="data.xml";
$data= new SimpleXMLElement($file, null, true);
$winner=intval($data->score[$winid]);
$loser=intval($data->score[$loseid]);
$exp_winner=expected($loser,$winner);
$new_win=win($winner,$exp_winner);
$exp_loser=expected($winner,$loser);
$new_lose=loss($loser,$exp_loser);
$data->score[$winid]=$new_win;
$data->score[$loseid]==$new_lose;
file_put_contents($file, $data->asXML(), LOCK_EX);
header("Location: index.php");
?>
```

Comment: `LOCK_EX` was added in 5.1, are you using at least this version on the host server?  Try `phpinfo()` to be sure.

Comment: I checked PHP version. It is- PHP Version 5.3.14

Comment: OK next question, how do you know it works on your local server?  Have you had many users hitting it simultaneously like you do on the hosted server?  If not, then you haven't really confirmed that it works locally.  It doesn't help you solve your problem directly but at least if you can reproduce it locally, you will have a lot less pain trying to debug it.

Comment: That is very strange, because `file_put_contents` would overwrite your file, so there must be something wrong while updating the data! Could you show us how you do that?

Comment: @leftclickben you are right, i cannot confirm that it works locally. But I cannot have a lot of users hitting it locally. I work alone.

Comment: @PrashantBaid Earlier you have also posted same question but more refined now but it seems you are doing things correctly but we need to know the code how you are wiring the XML. Starting and ending no problem seems but the data entering may cause problems, if you str_replace to do somethings...

Comment: @Vineet1982 But I am just updating the values. And I am nit using str_replace for doing anything. And if that was the problem, it shouldn't have worked in my localhost too, no?

Comment: @PrashantBaid  now let me know how you provide the $file variable and want to know it is possible that same name provided to two users or not

Comment: @PrashantBaid the reason is that file is created by two users. One user has big XML file but another user as less data compared to earlier bigger one

Comment: @Vineet1982 I edited my answer to add the $file variable code.

Comment: @Vineet1982 So what do you suggest I should do? Because I don't seem to find anything wrong in my code.

Comment: @PrashantBaid change the $file variable to dynamic and your problem would be solved or if you want to use same file then you have to open file as appending not as writing

Comment: @PrashantBaid try that and see if error exits

Comment: Looks like you've got a problem with atomic operations on that file. You might want to truncate it before writing into it. You also might want to test if you can aquire the lock. See as well http://www.php.net/flock and the examples given there.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing all occurrences of `$data->score['string']` to `$data->score->string`. See if it helps!

Example: change `$winner=intval($data->score[$winid]);` to `$winner=intval($data->score->$winid);`

Also, you have accidentally wrote two equal signs on this line `$data->score[$loseid]==$new_lose;`!

Comment: I tried this. It does not work. It in fact creates extra score tags which I don't want.